# group by and sum not working as expected in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi I have a simple dataframe with this structure

```
> str(allvalues)
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ seriesId        : Factor w/ 1 level "2021-02-28T00:00:00Z": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ forecastPoint   : Factor w/ 30 levels "790","791","792",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ rowId           : Factor w/ 30 levels "2021-03-01T00:00:00.000000Z",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ timestamp       : Factor w/ 65 levels "1842.6640625",..: 7 8 9 11 14 4 1 16 12 18 ...
 $ predictionValues: Factor w/ 1 level "total_visits (actual)": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ forecastDistance: Factor w/ 30 levels "1","10","11",..: 1 12 23 25 26 27 28 29 30 2 ...
 $ prediction      : num  2111 2130 2258 2276 2298 ...
 $ scenario        : Factor w/ 5 levels "0 0 10 10 10",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
```

and I want to group by "scenario" and sum "prediction"

but when I use

```
> allvalues %>% group_by(scenario) %>% summarise(cond_disp = sum(prediction))
  cond_disp
1  351940.8
```

Is not grouping by scenarios, there should be 5 rows, each scenario and the sum

any help on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Better use `dput(allvalues)` to share your data.

Comment: It seems to be a case of `plyr::summarise` ussage instead of `dplyr::summarise`.  specify `dplyr::summarize` to avoid masking